# how to set a unviersal button that can do mutiple function in python

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to make a financial calculator by using GUI, which can calculate some basic calculation functions.
Currently my program has main two functions `future_value` and `present_value`.
But when I calculate, it will call my previous function and print out the result on the terminal. For example, my previous function is `future_value`, and now there is a new function called `present_value`. When I press the calculation button, It will also call `future_value` in the terminal and print it out,but I only want `present_value` to be called.
I want to set the cauculation button as `universal button`, so whenever there is a blank in a block, then computer know I need to calculte that `specific number(function)`.
One of my idea is that create a function that like a `title(heading) function`, and that function is connected to this button, and within this function, there is a list of different functions that do something like calculte  interest rate, or present_value, etc, but my main problem is how should I do it, how should I use `if statement`  or other statement to work on it.

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class COMPOUND_INTEREST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = QUiLoader().load("bb\IA compound  designer.ui")
        self.ui.setWindowTitle("Compound interest")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.future_value)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.present_value)

    def future_value(self):
        N = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        I = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        PV = float(self.ui.lineEdit_3.text())
        C_Y = int(self.ui.lineEdit_7.text())
        jb = (1 + (I / (100 * C_Y))) ** N
        res = abs(jb * PV)
        print(res)
        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setText(str(round(res, 2)))

    def present_value(self):
        F_V = float(self.ui.lineEdit_6.text())
        N = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        I = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        C_Y = int(self.ui.lineEdit_7.text())
        x = (1 + (I / (100 * C_Y))) ** N
        res = -abs(F_V / x)
        print(res)
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText(str(round(res, 2)))


app = QApplication([])
COMPOUND_INTEREST = COMPOUND_INTEREST()
COMPOUND_INTEREST.ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: How do you expect the user to specify which one to do?  You either need multiple buttons (like a calculator), or you need a radio button set to pick which calculation to do.

Comment: for example, if I leave interest rate as blank, then computer will know user want to caulculate interest.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood on your post, you want a single button to change its functionality based on wether the *Line Edits* are **filled with numbers** or **empty**, right?

Just be careful because it gets more complex than that. For example: what if **both** of the *Line Edits* are filled with numbers? Or **both** of them are empty?

In the example below, I teach you how to check those 4 conditions, and ask the user to choose which method that should be executed it happens that both Edits are filled.

If both are empty, an error is displayed on the screen telling the user to fill at least one of them.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QDialog
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout

class OurCondition(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        text = "Both <b>Present</b> and <b>Future</b> fields are filled. Which function "
        text += "do you want to execute?"

        layout.addWidget(QLabel(text))

        bbox = QDialogButtonBox()
        bbox.addButton('Future Value', QDialogButtonBox.AcceptRole)
        bbox.addButton('Present Value', QDialogButtonBox.AcceptRole)
        bbox.addButton('Cancel', QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole)
        bbox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        bbox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        bbox.clicked.connect(self.clickedBeforeAccept)
        layout.addWidget(bbox)

        # Set Default Option
        self.conditionOption = 0

        # As we are using bbox on clickedBeforeAccept below, we must reference
        # bbox for later usage:
        self.bbox = bbox

    # Custom function to be called when a QDialogButtonBox button
    # is clicked.
    def clickedBeforeAccept(self, button):
        if (self.bbox.buttonRole(button) == QDialogButtonBox.AcceptRole):
            if (button.text() == 'Future Value'):
                self.conditionOption = 1
            else:
                self.conditionOption = 2

    def exec(self):
        self.exec_()

        # Return which option the user selected. Default is 0 (None).
        if (self.result() == QDialog.Accepted):
            return self.conditionOption

class Scene(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        editN = QLineEdit()
        editI = QLineEdit()
        editPV = QLineEdit()
        editFV = QLineEdit()
        editCY = QLineEdit()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(QLabel("N"), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(editN, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel("I"), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(editI, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel("Present:"), 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(editPV, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel("Future:"), 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(editFV, 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel("C/Y"), 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(editCY, 4, 1)

        layout.addLayout(grid)
        layout.addSpacing(12)

        button = QPushButton("Calculate")
        layout.addWidget(button)

        # Connecting methods to each widget:
        button.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
        
        # As we may reference these variables within the methods
        # of our class, we bind them to the scene class
        self.editI = editI
        self.editN = editN
        self.editPV = editPV
        self.editFV = editFV
        self.editCY = editCY

    # Note I'm not using QUiLoader. So self.ui is not available
    # here.
    def future_value(self):
        N = int(self.editN.text())
        I = float(self.editI.text())
        PV = float(self.editPV.text())
        C_Y = int(self.editCY.text())
        jb = (1 + (I / (100 * C_Y))) ** N
        res = abs(jb * PV)
        print(res)

        self.editFV.setText(str(round(res, 2)))

    def present_value(self):
        F_V = float(self.editFV.text())
        N = int(self.editN.text())
        I = float(self.editI.text())
        C_Y = int(self.editCY.text())
        x = (1 + (I / (100 * C_Y))) ** N
        res = -abs(F_V / x)
        print(res)
        
        self.editPV.setText(str(round(res, 2)))

    def calculate(self):
        # As each element in the scene is being referenced from
        # this class, we can access them using the self variable.
        #
        # To choose which operation, we must inform the application
        # which widget is empty before calling a calculation method:

        fv_empty = (self.editFV.text() == "")
        pv_empty = (self.editPV.text() == "")

        # If both inputs are empty, show an error dialog. That cannot
        # happen based on the current rules.
        if (fv_empty and pv_empty):
            text = 'Both Present and Future Values Fields are blank. ' 
            text += 'Fill at least one of them.'
            dialog = QMessageBox()
            dialog.setWindowTitle('Error')
            dialog.setText(text)
            dialog.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            dialog.exec_()

        # If both inputs are filled, create a rule and ask the user if
        # it wants to continue, otherwise, do nothing:
        elif (not fv_empty and not pv_empty):
            dialog = OurCondition()
            choice = dialog.exec()

            # Inside OutCondition class we defined if the user
            # clicked on Future Value button, choice is set to 1.
            #
            # If Present Value button is clicked, choice is set to 2.
            #
            # If it clicks on Cancel, or x button, choice is set to 0.

            if (choice == 1):
                self.future_value()
            elif (choice == 2):
                self.present_value()

        # At least one field is empty:
        else:
            # If Future Field is empty, then call future_value to fill it
            if (fv_empty):
                self.future_value()

            # If Present Field is empty, then call present_value to fill it
            elif (pv_empty):
                self.present_value()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Compound Test')

        scene = Scene()
        self.setCentralWidget(scene)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

If you want, you can also use *QComboBoxes* to let the user choose from multiple options, if you need 3 or more methods to execute from the single button. As the number of options grows, it gets harder to create a logic using the conditions of wether each input is empty or filled.

With only 2 of them, that's ok. But with 3 or more, I strongly recomend you to rethink your User Interface and add a *QComboBox*.

If that's still not what you wanted, please edit your question to state what is that you're struggling at.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your answer is right, and thank you very much for your feedback. Do you have any specific tutorials that I can follow, because our teacher taught us to use pysimplegui, but I didn't understand it very much and I don't have to use that. I saw QT by myself online and followed it, but it's not that deep yet. Do you have a series of tutorials that I can follow? At the same time, thank you for teaching me. I will look at the code you write carefully and I will definitely use QComboBox, because I need to also calculte interest rate and others.

Comment: Everything that I've learned was (in the hard way) by studying and practicing using the PySide2 API. There are of course many examples on the internet, but the Qt sites provides lots of useful examples.

Comment: The difficult thing about using their sites is that many examples are not in python, but in C++. You just have to know that PySide2 is a bound API from C++ Qt, so all methods will work using python objects. With that in mind, whenever you see an example using the Qt5, it should work in PySide2.

Comment: @pythonlearner Try the [Zetcode PyQt tutorial](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) and/or the [RealPython PyQt Calculator tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/). There are [some differences between PyQt5 and PySide2](https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt5-vs-pyside2/), but they should mostly work the same.

Comment: really appriciate for all of your helps!!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to learn how to parse an input. Basically you need to make an algorithm that checks if the user has input the interest rate.

Then, you make a conditional statement that says

```
if inputHasInterestRate() == false:
   presentValue()
else:
   futureValue()
```

Comment: but how should I make sure that each of function will not interfere to each other